# How can I tell ProGuard to not touch a class?

Tags: java, proguard

I have a config file with:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

-keep class mypackage.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers mypackage.** {
    *;
}
```

But in the obfuscated jar I see all my classes from mypackage changed (the size is reduced).

What was the change in my classes if I configured it to not obfuscate them?

How can I configure ProGuard to let a class go unchanged?